# Making a Java web browser read HTML and CSS better?

Tags: java, html, css, web

Ok, so what I have is a Java web browser that isn't very good. Here is my website in it.
![enter image description here][1]

And this is what it should look like.![enter image description here][2]

Comment: And how exactly are you displaying it? Code would be appreciated.

Comment: He is using a undergraduate's `JTextPane` browser project, i guess

Comment: Each browser views a website differently. This is why it looks different on Chrome and your custom browser. We can't help you without a code.

Answer (score 2):

Without code, it's hard to give a specific answer, but heres a general overview:

Java has a pretty bad record when it comes to trying to interpret anything beyond basic HTML. In the docs for the `javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet` class, it mentions that future versions will provide better CSS support, however this has been a long time in the making.

There was talk about better support in the form of a class `JWebPane` that provided WebKit support to improve support, but again this was never realised (more [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alex2d/archive/2008/12/jwebpane_projec.html))

I would recommend looking at using something like the JavaFX class [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) which provides pretty complete support for HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript (integration info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm))

Comment: This answer has some inaccuracies.  WebKit inclusion in Java was accomplished via WebKit.  WebView on the desktop uses WebKit.  Chrome uses Blink.  JavaFX is included in the Oracle JRE as part of the Java platform and is not a library.  Perhaps some of these things are pedantic, but that is why I downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that your program is messup a little with the CSS part. I assume that your program does not have the support of thhe class `WebView`. This class provides (though not all the features like storage) almost all the features of HTML5 and CSS3. You can find more details of the WebView class here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm . Hope that helped.

Comment: Perfect answer... I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a jTextPane browser, you could try to replace jTextPane with [SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox). According to my tests, it displays your page correctly.